# VMWare snapshots per batch job

Tags: vmware-esxi

With the vShpere client it is possible to create snopshots manually. Is there a way to trigger snapshots of of a running vm (ESXI 4.1) by a scheduled batch job ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [vSphere PowerCLI](http://www.vmware.com/go/PowerCLI). It's a powershell plugin.

To create a snapshot, you would need to do the following:

```
add-pssnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core
Connect-VIServer -Server myVSphereServer
get-vm myVMName | new-snapshot -name "My New Snapshot"
```

Comment: is vSphere PowerCLI a free or commercial product?

Comment: Free add-on for Powershell ;-)